# How to make Iot Edge message routing between modules work on arm32 (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, azure-iot-edge

I created an Iot Edge solution using Visual Studio Code via **View -> Command Palette... -> AzureIotEdge:NewIoTEdgeSolution** using the **C# Module** Module Template.  This generates an Iot Edge solution with two Modules: **tempSensor** creates messages with dummy telemetry-data and **SampleModule** is supposed to receive those messages, print them and then pass them on to IotHub.

I build the solution for **arm32** and deployed it to a Rasperry Pi (running latest Raspbian).  The modules are then displayed as running on the device but if I monitor d2c-messages there are none arriving in IoT Hub.

If I run **sudo iotedge logs tempSensor -f** on the device, I can see messages are being generated.

If I run **sudo iotedge logs SampleModule -f** I only see *IoT Hub module client initialized.* Which is logged in the Init() Method.  There is no logging from the PipeMessage Method which seems not to be reached at all.

If I build the solution for amd64 and deploy it to a virtual machine, everything is working as expected.

Is there a way to get it working on a Raspberry Pi running Raspian?

By the way: I tried the **Azure Functions C#** Module Template as well. Same result: On amd64 it works but on arm32 it does not.

UPDATE:
Here is the logging of **edgeAgent**:

```
            █████╗ ███████╗██╗   ██╗██████╗ ███████╗
       ██╔══██╗╚══███╔╝██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔════╝
       ███████║  ███╔╝ ██║   ██║██████╔╝█████╗
       ██╔══██║ ███╔╝  ██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝
       ██║  ██║███████╗╚██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗
       ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝

 ██╗ ██████╗ ████████╗    ███████╗██████╗  ██████╗ ███████╗
 ██║██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝    ██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔════╝ ██╔════╝
 ██║██║   ██║   ██║       █████╗  ██║  ██║██║  ███╗█████╗
 ██║██║   ██║   ██║       ██╔══╝  ██║  ██║██║   ██║██╔══╝
 ██║╚██████╔╝   ██║       ███████╗██████╔╝╚██████╔╝███████╗
 ╚═╝ ╚═════╝    ╚═╝       ╚══════╝╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝

2018-12-21 07:08:27.323 +00:00 [INF] - Edge agent attempting to connect to IoT Hub via Amqp_Tcp_Only...
2018-12-21 07:08:31.986 +00:00 [INF] - Created persistent store at /tmp/edgeAgent
2018-12-21 07:08:34.193 +00:00 [INF] - Edge agent connected to IoT Hub via Amqp_Tcp_Only.
2018-12-21 07:08:37.624 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution started for deployment 8
2018-12-21 07:08:37.654 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Stop module SampleModule"
2018-12-21 07:08:37.766 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Remove module SampleModule"
2018-12-21 07:08:37.964 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Saving SampleModule to store"
2018-12-21 07:08:38.141 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Command Group: (
  [Create module SampleModule2]
  [Start module SampleModule2]
)"
2018-12-21 07:08:38.152 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Create module SampleModule2"
2018-12-21 07:08:42.678 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Start module SampleModule2"
2018-12-21 07:08:45.749 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Command Group: (
  [Stop module tempSensor]
  [Start module tempSensor]
  [Saving tempSensor to store]
)"
2018-12-21 07:08:45.750 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Stop module tempSensor"
2018-12-21 07:08:45.759 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Start module tempSensor"
2018-12-21 07:08:48.423 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Saving tempSensor to store"
2018-12-21 07:08:48.491 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Command Group: (
  [Stop module edgeHub]
  [Start module edgeHub]
  [Saving edgeHub to store]
)"
2018-12-21 07:08:48.491 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Stop module edgeHub"
2018-12-21 07:08:48.501 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Start module edgeHub"
2018-12-21 07:08:51.895 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Saving edgeHub to store"
2018-12-21 07:08:51.900 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution ended for deployment 8
2018-12-21 07:08:52.743 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties
2018-12-21 07:08:57.811 +00:00 [INF] - HealthRestartPlanner is clearing restart stats for module 'tempSensor' as it has been running healthy for 00:10:00.
2018-12-21 07:08:57.814 +00:00 [INF] - HealthRestartPlanner is clearing restart stats for module 'edgeHub' as it has been running healthy for 00:10:00.
2018-12-21 07:08:57.815 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution started for deployment 8
2018-12-21 07:08:57.818 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Saving tempSensor to store"
2018-12-21 07:08:57.819 +00:00 [INF] - Executing command: "Saving edgeHub to store"
2018-12-21 07:08:57.820 +00:00 [INF] - Plan execution ended for deployment 8
2018-12-21 07:08:58.038 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties
2018-12-21 07:09:03.239 +00:00 [INF] - Updated reported properties
```

And here some of the logging of **edgeHub** (there is lots more but seems to be all the same Exceptions):

```
2018-12-21 07:28:23.450 +00:00 [WRN] - Error sending messages to module bewaPi1/SampleModule2
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at DotNetty.Buffers.HeapArena.NewChunk(Int32 pageSize, Int32 maxOrder, Int32 pageShifts, Int32 chunkSize)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.AllocateNormal(PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity, Int32 normCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.Allocate(PoolThreadCache`1 cache, PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PooledByteBufferAllocator.NewHeapBuffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.AbstractByteBufferAllocator.Buffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ByteBufferConverter.ToByteBuffer(Byte[] bytes) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ByteBufferConverter.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.FromMessage(IMessage message) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.DeviceProxy.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/DeviceProxy.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Device.DeviceMessageHandler.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/device/DeviceMessageHandler.cs:line 256
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Routing.ModuleEndpoint.ModuleMessageProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass5_2.<<ProcessAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/routing/ModuleEndpoint.cs:line 98
2018-12-21 07:28:28.517 +00:00 [WRN] - Non retryable exception occurred while sending message.
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at DotNetty.Buffers.HeapArena.NewChunk(Int32 pageSize, Int32 maxOrder, Int32 pageShifts, Int32 chunkSize)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.AllocateNormal(PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity, Int32 normCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.Allocate(PoolThreadCache`1 cache, PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PooledByteBufferAllocator.NewHeapBuffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.AbstractByteBufferAllocator.Buffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ByteBufferConverter.ToByteBuffer(Byte[] bytes) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ByteBufferConverter.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.FromMessage(IMessage message) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.DeviceProxy.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/DeviceProxy.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Device.DeviceMessageHandler.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/device/DeviceMessageHandler.cs:line 256
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Routing.ModuleEndpoint.ModuleMessageProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass5_2.<<ProcessAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/routing/ModuleEndpoint.cs:line 98
2018-12-21 07:28:28.521 +00:00 [WRN] - Error sending messages to module bewaPi1/SampleModule2
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at DotNetty.Buffers.HeapArena.NewChunk(Int32 pageSize, Int32 maxOrder, Int32 pageShifts, Int32 chunkSize)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.AllocateNormal(PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity, Int32 normCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.Allocate(PoolThreadCache`1 cache, PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PooledByteBufferAllocator.NewHeapBuffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.AbstractByteBufferAllocator.Buffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ByteBufferConverter.ToByteBuffer(Byte[] bytes) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ByteBufferConverter.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.FromMessage(IMessage message) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.DeviceProxy.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/DeviceProxy.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Device.DeviceMessageHandler.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/device/DeviceMessageHandler.cs:line 256
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Routing.ModuleEndpoint.ModuleMessageProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass5_2.<<ProcessAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/routing/ModuleEndpoint.cs:line 98
2018-12-21 07:28:33.666 +00:00 [WRN] - Non retryable exception occurred while sending message.
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at DotNetty.Buffers.HeapArena.NewChunk(Int32 pageSize, Int32 maxOrder, Int32 pageShifts, Int32 chunkSize)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.AllocateNormal(PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity, Int32 normCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.Allocate(PoolThreadCache`1 cache, PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PooledByteBufferAllocator.NewHeapBuffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.AbstractByteBufferAllocator.Buffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ByteBufferConverter.ToByteBuffer(Byte[] bytes) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ByteBufferConverter.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.FromMessage(IMessage message) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.DeviceProxy.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/DeviceProxy.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Device.DeviceMessageHandler.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/device/DeviceMessageHandler.cs:line 256
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Routing.ModuleEndpoint.ModuleMessageProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass5_2.<<ProcessAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/routing/ModuleEndpoint.cs:line 98
2018-12-21 07:28:33.669 +00:00 [WRN] - Error sending messages to module bewaPi1/SampleModule2
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at DotNetty.Buffers.HeapArena.NewChunk(Int32 pageSize, Int32 maxOrder, Int32 pageShifts, Int32 chunkSize)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.AllocateNormal(PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity, Int32 normCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.Allocate(PoolThreadCache`1 cache, PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PooledByteBufferAllocator.NewHeapBuffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.AbstractByteBufferAllocator.Buffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ByteBufferConverter.ToByteBuffer(Byte[] bytes) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ByteBufferConverter.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.FromMessage(IMessage message) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.DeviceProxy.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/DeviceProxy.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Device.DeviceMessageHandler.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/device/DeviceMessageHandler.cs:line 256
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Routing.ModuleEndpoint.ModuleMessageProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass5_2.<<ProcessAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/routing/ModuleEndpoint.cs:line 98
2018-12-21 07:28:39.012 +00:00 [WRN] - Non retryable exception occurred while sending message.
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at DotNetty.Buffers.HeapArena.NewChunk(Int32 pageSize, Int32 maxOrder, Int32 pageShifts, Int32 chunkSize)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.AllocateNormal(PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity, Int32 normCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.Allocate(PoolThreadCache`1 cache, PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PooledByteBufferAllocator.NewHeapBuffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.AbstractByteBufferAllocator.Buffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ByteBufferConverter.ToByteBuffer(Byte[] bytes) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ByteBufferConverter.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.FromMessage(IMessage message) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.DeviceProxy.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/DeviceProxy.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Device.DeviceMessageHandler.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/device/DeviceMessageHandler.cs:line 256
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Routing.ModuleEndpoint.ModuleMessageProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass5_2.<<ProcessAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/routing/ModuleEndpoint.cs:line 98
2018-12-21 07:28:39.015 +00:00 [WRN] - Error sending messages to module bewaPi1/SampleModule2
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at DotNetty.Buffers.HeapArena.NewChunk(Int32 pageSize, Int32 maxOrder, Int32 pageShifts, Int32 chunkSize)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.AllocateNormal(PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity, Int32 normCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PoolArena`1.Allocate(PoolThreadCache`1 cache, PooledByteBuffer`1 buf, Int32 reqCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.PooledByteBufferAllocator.NewHeapBuffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at DotNetty.Buffers.AbstractByteBufferAllocator.Buffer(Int32 initialCapacity, Int32 maxCapacity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ByteBufferConverter.ToByteBuffer(Byte[] bytes) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ByteBufferConverter.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.FromMessage(IMessage message) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/ProtocolGatewayMessageConverter.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt.DeviceProxy.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Mqtt/DeviceProxy.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Device.DeviceMessageHandler.SendMessageAsync(IMessage message, String input) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/device/DeviceMessageHandler.cs:line 256
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Routing.ModuleEndpoint.ModuleMessageProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass5_2.<<ProcessAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core/routing/ModuleEndpoint.cs:line 98
```

So the problem is caused by System.OutOfMemoryExceptions.  But what is causing those exceptions?

**Update2**: This seems to be a known problem (see [here](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/475)) and can be solved by Setting **OptimizeForPerformance** to **false**.  I will try this and see if it works.

Comment: Could you share logs of edgeHub and edgeAgent (`sudo iotedge logs <module name>`)?

Comment: I added the logs above.  There are a lot of System.OutOfMemoryExceptions in edgeHub.  Any idea what is causing the exceptions?

Comment: @LazarusX thank's for requesting the logs of the edgeHub module.  This made me look in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the issue related to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot#stability-issues-on-resource-constrained-devices

Please refer the link and turn off OptimizeForPerformance in deployment manifest.

Comment: I just found that out myself and posted an answer in exactly the same moment :-) I will accept your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

The message routing between modules does not work because of System.OutOfMemoryExceptions in the edgeHub module.  The problem is described and discussed [here](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/475).

Microsoft has implemented a solution which is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot#stability-issues-on-resource-constrained-devices).

In short:  If running IotEdge Solutions on Raspberry Pi the environment variable **OptimizeForPerformance** has to be set to **false**.

Comment: From Azure docs: "Don't optimize for performance on constrained devices
The IoT Edge hub is optimized for performance by default, so it attempts to allocate large chunks of memory. This configuration can cause stability problems on smaller devices like the Raspberry Pi. If you're deploying devices with constrained resources, you may want to set the OptimizeForPerformance environment variable to false on the IoT Edge hub.